# Explanation for this simplification

Tags: factorial

I don't quite understand the following simplification. I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around exactly why this works. Is there some kind of simple example that someone could give me to make it "click"? Is there some sort of "rule" I can apply in similar situations?

$$(k+1)!\cdot (k+2)-1 = (k+2)!-1$$

Comment: Not sure what to tag this as, but I've run into this problem while doing discrete mathematics homework.

Comment: Are you okay with say 6! is the same as 5! *6 ?

Comment: Hint : $(k+1)!$ is the product of the positive integers upto $k+1$ and $(k+2)!$ is the product of the positive integers upto $k+2$

Comment: @randomgirl So if I understand correctly, basically k+2 is the "final" step similar to how *6 is the final step in 6!.

Comment: I think I get what you are calling final step... and if so yes.  But if not, here is a little more to add: write 6! as 6*5*4*3*2*1 first then write the 5*4*3*2*1 as 5! .  Now the more abstract example of (k+2)! being (k+1)!*(k+2) should make a little more sense.  k+2 is just one more than k+1.  Here is another abstract example:  k! can be written as (k-1)!*k.

Comment: Sorry for not typing in the preferred math latex language.  I had a brain fart about doing it or how to do it.  Long day :p

Comment: @randomgirl Alright I think this makes sense, and in retrospect is quite simple. In this case it only works because K+2 is one higher than K+1 (right?). In any case, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Yes.  You can also say $(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1) \cdot k!$ or that $(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)(k) \cdot (k-1)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The factorial is defined recursively as:

$0!=1 \qquad (n+1)!=n!\cdot (n+1)$

so
$$
(k+2)!=(k+1)!(k+2)
$$
by definition.